# Bootstrap grid does not adjust according to scaling

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a webpage using bootstrap 4 grid. It displays fine on 1920 * 1080 with 100% scaling.

If I change the scaling to 150% (which is recommended), the website does not adjust accordingly.

Does bootstrap adjust according to scale? (How can I change it to use col-sm-12 when scaling is more than 100%?)

**Code:**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12" >
                   <!-- content -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12" >
                   <!-- content -->
            </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use .container for a responsive fixed width container.

```
<div class ="container">
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12" >
                   <!-- content -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12" >
                   <!-- content -->
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and make sure you add the viewport meta tag to your .

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

you can also use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

**Update:**

I was thinking if you can use in your container class max-width and max-height.

```
max-width: 1920px
max-height: 1080px
// or try to set the height:auto
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> in the head tag. Also, my website is inside  <div class="container-fluid"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div> but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @developer have you tried using only <div class ="container"> ?

Comment: @developer I've updated my answer. can you try add max-width and max-height

Comment: I tried max-width and max-height and container class but no luck.